# Selenium on linux server can't bypass login, but works on local machine

Tags: python-3.x, linux, selenium-chromedriver

I have a python script that uses selenium to login into a certain site. But after entering the corrent credentials, the dashboard won't allow the script to go through. Instead, it gives us a "403: Forbidden Error". The weird thing is that it works on my local machine, but that behavior only occurs on the Digital Ocean server.

This is the code that I have created:

```
chrome_options = Options()
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36'
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={user_agent}')

PROXY = proxies[10].get_address()
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",

}

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=chrome_options)

pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    "source": """
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
      get: () => undefined
    });

    if (window.self === window.top) { // if main document
        console.log('add script');
      }
  """
})

driver.get("https://ahrefs.com/user/login")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))

for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

"""
  3. Fill in the username and password, then click the login button.
"""
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "email_input")))
    email = driver.find_element_by_id('email_input')
    password_ = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
    login_btn = driver.find_element_by_id('SignInButton')
    login_form = driver.find_element_by_id('formLogin')

    # TEST-ACCOUNT
    email.send_keys('{email_address}')
    password_.send_keys('{password}')

    login_btn.click()
    driver.save_screenshot(os.path.join(project_dir, 'login-checking.png'))
except TimeoutError as e:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

print("Successfully logged in..")
time.sleep(10.0)
driver.get('https://ahrefs.com/batch-analysis')
print(driver.current_url)
driver.save_screenshot(os.path.join(project_dir, 'login-ok.png'))
```